# ErrorException in Util.php line 206: Function create_function() is deprecated

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello when installing my script I'm getting the following error:

ErrorException in Util.php line 206:
Function create_function () is deprecated

my code

```
{
    // php doesn't garbage collect functions created by create_function ()
    // so use a static variable to avoid adding a new function to memory
    // every time this function is called.
    static $ callbacks = array ();
    if (! isset ($ callbacks [$ delimiter])) {
        $ callbacks [$ delimiter] = create_function ('$ matches', "return '$ delimiter'. strtolower (\ $ matches [1]);");
    }

    return preg_replace_callback ('/ ([A-Z]) /', $ callbacks [$ delimiter], $ string);
}
```

Comment: already tried but then returns me another error


new error:
FatalThrowableError in Util.php line 206:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' $ matches '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: already tried but then returns me another error


code:

    // php doesn't garbage collect functions created by create_function ()
        // so use a static variable to avoid adding a new function to memory
        // every time this function is called.
        static $ callbacks = array ();
        if (! isset ($ callbacks [$ delimiter])) {
            $ callbacks [$ delimiter] = function ('$ matches', return '$ delimiter'. strtolower (\ $ matches [1]); ");
        }